# Flex horizontally in column layout

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox

Is there a way to flex a div horizontally inside of a column layout? Or would I have to wrap it in a row layout?

Example:

```
<div layout="column" style="height: 100%" flex="50">
```

I would like the flex to take 50% of the width of the page.  This makes it take 50% of the height.  Do I have to put this inside of a `<div layout="row"></div>` or is there a way to force it to flex horizontally?

### Edit

I'm also looking to change the width depending on browser size so simply adding `width=50%` does not work for me. I want something like `flex-lg="50" flex-sm="70"`.

Comment: grid will be the display mode to use soon :) can you set a concrete example ? a single div doesn't show much ...

Comment: How about using `inline-flex`?

Comment: Sorry @GCyrillus, I forgot to add something to my question. I edited it

Comment: @Pangloss, could you provide an example, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: The correct tag is `flexbox`, not `flex`, which is something else entirely.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmm5a7z/ - how about this?

Comment: width/ min-width can be updated via mediaqueries if that helps you to relay on it

Comment: Are you actually using angular material?

Comment: That only useful if you want to have multiple flexboxes in a row.

Comment: Yes I am using angular material